# Question about a Proof of Triangularizing a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I was questioned from my friend about a non-proof in a linear algebra textbook.

The author mentions that the following proof of the theorem, that every square matrix in $\Bbb{C}$ is triangularizable, has a gap and thus is invalid:

---

First, we have two preliminary lemmas.

> **Lemma 1.** Let $I_m$ be the identity matrix of size $m$, $A\in \mathfrak{M}_{m\times m}(\Bbb{C})$, and $U, B \in \mathfrak{M}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{C})$ such that $U$ is invertible. Then
>   $$ \bigg(\begin{matrix} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & U^{-1} \end{matrix}\bigg) \bigg( \begin{matrix} A & * \\ 0 & B \end{matrix} \bigg) \bigg( \begin{matrix} I_m & 0 \\ 0 & U \end{matrix} \bigg) = \bigg( \begin{matrix} A & * \\ 0 & U^{-1}BU \end{matrix} \bigg). $$
>
> **Lemma 2.** Let $A \in \mathfrak{M}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{C})$. Then there exists an eigenvalue $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$ and an invertible matrix $U \in \mathfrak{M}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{C})$ such that
>   $$ U^{-1}AU = \bigg( \begin{matrix} \lambda & * \\ 0 & * \end{matrix} \bigg).$$
>
> *Proof.* Let $v_1 \in \Bbb{C}^n$ be a nonzero eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. Let $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ be a basis of $\Bbb{C}^n$ containing $v_1$. Let $U$ be a matrix whose $k$-th column is $v_k$. Then
>   $$[AU]_{*1} = A[U]_{*1} = Av_1 = \lambda v_1 = \lambda [U]_{*1}$$
>   and hence
>   $$ [U^{-1}AU]_{i1} = [U^{-1}]_{ij}[AU]_{j1} = \lambda [U^{-1}]_{ij}[U]_{j1} = \lambda \delta_{i1},$$
>   which proves Lemma 2.

Now we claim that for each $1 \leq k \leq n$ there exist

- an upper-triangular matrix $T_k$ of size $k$,
- a square matrix $A_{n-k}$ of size $n-k$, and
- an invertible matrix $U_k \in \mathfrak{M}_{n\times n}(\Bbb{C})$

such that

$$ U_k^{-1} A U_k = \bigg( \begin{matrix} T_k & * \\ 0 & A_{n-k} \end{matrix} \bigg).$$

In particular, for $k = n$ this implies that $A$ is triangularizable.

We prove this claim by induction on $k$. For $k = 1$, this is a trivial consequence of Lemma 2. Now assume this holds for $k < n$. Then applying Lemma 2 to $A_{n-k}$, we obtain some $\tilde{\lambda} \in \Bbb{C}$ and an invertible matrix $\tilde{U}$ of size $n-k$ such that

$$ \tilde{U}^{-1}A_{n-k}\tilde{U} = \bigg( \begin{matrix} \tilde{\lambda} & * \\ 0 & A_{n-k-1} \end{matrix} \bigg).$$

Now let $U_{k+1}$ as

$$U_{k+1} = U_k \bigg( \begin{matrix} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde{U} \end{matrix} \bigg). $$

Then

$$\begin{align*} U_{k+1}^{-1} A U_{k+1}
&= \bigg( \begin{matrix} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde{U}^{-1} \end{matrix} \bigg) U_k^{-1} A U_k \bigg( \begin{matrix} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde{U} \end{matrix} \bigg) 
= \bigg( \begin{matrix} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde{U}^{-1} \end{matrix} \bigg) \bigg( \begin{matrix} T_k & * \\ 0 & A_{n-k} \end{matrix} \bigg) \bigg( \begin{matrix} I_k & 0 \\ 0 & \tilde{U} \end{matrix} \bigg) \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} T_k & * \\ 0 & \tilde{U}^{-1}A_{n-k}\tilde{U} \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} T_k & * & * \\ 0 & \tilde{\lambda} & * \\ 0 & 0 &  A_{n-k-1} \end{pmatrix}
=: \begin{pmatrix} T_{k+1} & * \\ 0 &  A_{n-k-1} \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}$$

Therefore the claim follows by induction and the proof is complete. Q.E.D.

---

Actually, I was convinced by this argument and was unable to find any gap in this proof.

The book says that this non-proof overlooked the importance of $L$-invariant subspaces. So I tried this non-proof with some examples of $A$ where the multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is greater than the dimension of the kernel of $A - \lambda I$ in hopes that these trials would reveal the fault in the argument above. But it ended up only finding that the algorithm above works in those cases. I want to know what I am missing.

Comment: What is an $L$-invariant subspace?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, For a linear operator $L : V \to V$, $W \leq V$ is called a [$L$-invariant subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace) if $L(W) \leq W$.

Comment: Yes, okay, but what is $L$? I don't see you refer to an operator named $L$ in this proof. (I would have just asked "what is $L$" but I wasn't sure if "$L$-invariance" had some other definition unfamiliar to me.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't find a gap in the proof either, but let me just comment that the proof works far too hard. As Emil Artin once said,

> It is my experience that proofs involving matrices can be shortened by 50% if one throws the matrices out.

I think this proof gets shortened even more than that. Let $A : V \to V$ be a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional complex vector space $V$. We will define inductively a basis $v_1, ... v_n$ of $V$ such that $A$ preserves $V_k = \text{span}(v_1, ... v_k)$. This is equivalent to $A$ being upper-triangular with respect to this basis. Define $v_1$ to be an eigenvector of $A$ (say with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$). If $v_1, ... v_k$ have been defined, then $A$ preserves $V_k$, hence acts on $V/V_k$, hence has some eigenvector there (this is the crucial step!). Let $v_{k+1}$ be any element of $V$ mapping to such an eigenvector (say with eigenvalue $\lambda_{k+1}$). Then $A v_{k+1} \equiv \lambda_{k+1} v_{k+1} \bmod V_k$, hence $A$ preserves $V_{k+1}$. The conclusion follows.

(The subspaces $V_k$ form a [complete flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)), and "preserving a complete flag" is the basis-invariant way to say "upper-triangular.")

Comment: Some comments. The given proof, in working with a matrix instead of a linear transformation, artificially starts with a basis which is not useful and modifies it - but the problem is to find a basis which has a particular property, so why start with one which doesn't? It is cleaner to find the useful basis directly. In fact this argument shows almost without modification that a commuting family of linear operators can be simultaneously triangularized, and I wouldn't want to try writing this proof out explicitly using matrices (there would be a lot of subscripts).

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Maybe someone found a gap in the proof after all?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm relieved that my logical system embedded in my brain is still working fine. Thank you both for your confirmation and for a nice concise proof!